# Android HttpClient, DefaultHttpClient, HttpPost

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

How would I send a string data (`JSONObject.toString()`) to a url. I want to write a static method in a util class to do this. I want the method signature to be as follows

`public static String postData (String url, String postData) throws SomeCustomException`

What should be the format of the string url

The return String is the response from the server in as a string representation of json data.

#### EDIT

#### Present connection util

```
package my.package;
import my.package.exceptions.CustomException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


 public class ConnectionUtil {

 public static String postData(String url, String postData)
        throws CustomException {

    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String result = "";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost();
    httppost.setHeader("host", url);

    Log.v("ConnectionUtil", "Opening POST connection to URI = " + httppost.getURI() + " url = " + URLDecoder.decode(url));

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(postData));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new CustomException("Could not establish network connection");
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "utf-8"), 8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line = "0";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        throw new CustomException("Error parsing the response");
    }
    Log.v("ConnectionUtil", "Sent: "+postData);
    Log.v("ConnectionUtil", "Got result "+result);
    return result;

}

}
```

#### Logcat output

> 10-16 11:27:27.287: E/log_tag(4935): Error in http connection java.lang.NullPointerException
> 10-16 11:27:27.287: W/System.err(4935): java.lang.NullPointerException
> 10-16 11:27:27.287: W/System.err(4935):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:496)
> 10-16 11:27:27.307: W/System.err(4935):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
> 10-16 11:27:27.327: W/System.err(4935):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
> 10-16 11:27:27.327: W/System.err(4935):     at in.gharpay.zap.integration.ConnectionUtil.postData(ConnectionUtil.java:92)
> 10-16 11:27:27.327: W/System.err(4935):     at in.gharpay.zap.integration.ZapTransaction$1.doInBackground(ZapTransaction.java:54)
> 10-16 11:27:27.327: W/System.err(4935):     at in.gharpay.zap.integration.ZapTransaction$1.doInBackground(ZapTransaction.java:1)
> 10-16 11:27:27.327: W/System.err(4935):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
> 10-16 11:27:27.327: W/System.err(4935):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
> 10-16 11:27:27.327: W/System.err(4935):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
> 10-16 11:27:27.327: W/System.err(4935):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
> 10-16 11:27:27.327: W/System.err(4935):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
> 10-16 11:27:27.327: W/System.err(4935):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
> 10-16 11:27:27.327: V/log_tag(4935): Could not establish network connection

Comment: I think there is some problem with your POST method sending StringEntity to the server end.. Check out my latest answer and see if it works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your code the basic problem is caused by the way you are using `StringEntity` to `POST` parameters to your url. Check to see if the following code helps in posting your data to the server using `StringEntity`.

```
    // Build the JSON object to pass parameters
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("username", username);
    jsonObj.put("data", dataValue);

    // Create the POST object and add the parameters
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
    entity.setContentType("application/json");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

Hope this helps in solving your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I think this helped but I am still getting an runtime error UnknownHostException. I am sure my url works and checked from my browser. I also get the same error for google.com or example.com. How should I format the URL/URI? I want to hit the URL `http://xyz.mysite.com/some_page.php/` and post data. Do I need to also specify the port?

Comment: Just using 80. So that should be default. This is now working and hitting the server. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here are my thoughts on your question:-

1. First, you should simply send the data to the server by using `POST` method. Its easy and absolutely possible in Android also. A simple code snippet for sending `POST` data can be like:

   ```
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
           "http://yourserverIP/postdata.php");
   String serverResponse = null;
   try {
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("datakey1", dataValue1));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("datakey2",
               dataValue2));

       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

       serverResponse = response.getStatusLine().toString();
       Log.e("response", serverResponse);
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   The above code sends data to a PHP script `postdata` on your server.
2. Next, for parsing the `JSON` data sent by the server, you can use a `JSONParser` and then easily utilize it as per your needs. You can get the response returned from the server by using the following code:

   ```
   String jsonData = EntityUtils.toString(serverResponse.getEntity());
   ```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: I am not using a form. the server just wants to see string data. thats all.

Comment: @phodu_insaan Even for sending string data, you will need to send POST data to the server. So, you don't need to be using a form for sending string data to the server. And if you simply just want to send commands like passing just one parameter to the server, then you may also think about using GET method. I can help you with GET too.

Comment: I am doing almost the same thing. Instead of passing a `UrlEncodedFormEntity` I am passing a `new StringEntity` with my String data. I get a `NullPointerException`. Just appending my logcat output to the question.

Comment: Yes, plz add your LogCat output here.. And I am not able to get you, how are you passing a StringEntity?? Please add your code also that is performing this task.. That will help in understanding your problem in a better way..

Answer (score 1):

try using this method where strJsonRequest is the json string you want to post and the strUrl is the url to which you want to post the strJsonRequest

```
   public String urlPost(String strJsonRequest, String strURL) throws Exception 
{
    try
    {
        URL objURL = new URL(strURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)objURL.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECT_MILLIS);
        connection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_READ_MILLIS);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+strJsonRequest.toString().getBytes("UTF8").length);

        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

        byte [] b = strJsonRequest.getBytes("UTF-8");

        outputStream.write(b);
        outputStream.flush();

        inputstreamObj = (InputStream) connection.getContent();//getInputStream();

        if(inputstreamObj != null)
            strResponse = convertStreamToString(inputstreamObj);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    return strResponse;
}
```

and the method convertStreamToString() is as below

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
{
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
     */
    BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try
    {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally 
    {
        try 
        {
            is.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: what is the method `converStreamToString`?

Comment: what should be the url format? I am getting a `MalformedURLException`

Comment: am not sure what is the url that you are getting in the logcat once check whether its the same that you passed

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your server side code is set up, an example format of the url where your server has a php page to handle the API call would be:

```
http://yoururl.com/demo.php?jsondata=postData
```

If your are using a post connection you can simply say:

```
http://yoururl.com/demo.php
```

and pass it your post parameters i.e. the json string

Here is a great tutorial on how to do this:
http://yoururl.com/demo.php?jsondata=postData

Comment: the server accepts a post connection. So I just need the url like `http://www.example.com/my_page.php`, right?